# Unable to create Azure Function App in Visual Studio 2022 community edition - The Create button in the Additional details section is disabled

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022

Unable to create Azure Function App in Visual Studio 2022 community edition - The Create button in the Additional details section is disabled
[image]

On clicking Next, the Create button is disabled in the Additional details page. Frustrating as I don't know what is missing or what needs to be modified.
[image]

I'm able to create a Function App directly in the portal. I prefer using Studio as it's a better IDE. I have PIMed myself with the appropriate user role to a resource group. However, while connecting through Visual Studio, I'm not even shown options of selecting the Resource Group / App Plan etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. To create an Azure function, you need **Azure Function Core Tools**.

- To add Azure Function Core tools, go to `Visual Studio => Tools` => Get Tools and Features` and include the **Azure development** workload=> Click on ***Install while downloading***.

[image]

2. Go to  `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools` in ***File Manager***, delete **AzureFunctionsTools** folder. It gets generated again when you open Visual Studio.
3. If still issue persists, go to  `Tools=>Options=>Projects and Solutions=>`check if you can see `Azure Functions`, if yes, click *check for updates*.

[image]